# multiple redirects in .htaccess file - execute first one

Tags: server, apache2, .htaccess

I am attempting to use .htaccess to redirect a single page in expression engine to another site's page. Our .htaccess file has a ton of other rewrite rules and rewrite conditions to ensure the expression engine site runs effectively.

I have this RedirectMatch at the top of the .htaccess file.

```
RedirectMatch (?i)^/my-page https://www.differentsite.com/my-page
```

The redirect is sending to the new site okay except for it's adding an extra '?/my-page' at the end of my url on the target server. So it is coming through as "https://www.differentsite.com/my-page?/my-page"

I believe this is because of some other rules below this one in the .htaccess files appending/attempting to some extra parts of URLs.

How I ensure that only the first line is executed using .htaccess?

Also, is there a way I can test what exactly the .htaccess URL is trying to send before it goes, through some type of access/log file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `[L]` flag at the end of the line. Think, might help.

```
RedirectMatch (?i)^/my-page https://www.differentsite.com/my-page [L]
```

More about flags in .htaccess [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39225280/9301142)

Answer (score 0):

@atom_n was correct that I needed a L flag!

However, the L flag does not work for RedirectMatch so I had to use a rewrite rule. The final working solution is below

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /my-page [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.differentsite.com/my-page [R=301,L]
```

It worked perfectly after that.